# What is the history life of Cessna 172 airplane?

Tags: general-aviation

How can i find manufacture date of cessna 172P knowing serial number?

Answer (score 1):

[You can try the FAA's look up](https://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/Search/SerialNumberInquiry), the field you are looking for once you click on the N-Number is `MFR Year`